# How to check if internet connection was lost WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

How can I check if internet connection was lost in WP7.I'm developing social app and if internet connection was lost I have FileNotFoundException.I can't use try/catch because its doesn't prevent my app from closing with exception.Also `if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())` works only from time to time and not always shows the truth.

Comment: On a side note I believe `NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()` responds true when the Interface is deemed 'up'. My experience using a Bluetooth library was this would return true up until a `send` failed and would then mark it false... otherwise one operation too late for the check to be of any use. My workaround was sending a test ping then checking the flag for a `true` and continuing from there.

Comment: If you can't trap the exception then somethign is very wrong. There is no reason that a lost network connection should cause your app to crash. Can you show an example of what you're doing to cause this.

Comment: ` if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
                lock (this) {
                    WebClient c = new WebClient();
                    c.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(websiteURL));
                    c.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(dialogs_check);

                }...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only reliable way I have found is to ping something reliable.  My customer set up a "ping" call on the server that I need to access, which is the ultimate test.  If I can reach that call, I can (or shoule be able to) reach any of them.

Comment: How I can do this on windows phone?

Comment: I use a standard HttpWebRequest.

Answer (score 2):

```
        bool isAvailable = NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
        if (isAvailable == false)
        {
            //Logic here
        }
        else
        {
             //Code
        }
```

It works all the time for me...

Comment: No, this isn't true way. For example I have internet connection, but the site doesn't respond.

Answer (score 0):

`NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()` doesnt seem to work correctly all the time. Its better to use `WebClient` object to download some URL which you are sure is available always.

Answer (score 0):

@Francesco : I think you are right,  `NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()` works fine on phone, but its unreliable on emulator.